# How to use a uploaded .csv file in a f selector feature selection function. now it is been accessed by the imported dataset in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am a beginner in r shiny. so please help me that how can i access the uploaded .csv file to do the feature selection. because now i am doing the feature selection by importing the data set to the r studio environment

I have tried on r studio and rshiny app

```
# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions -enter code here  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      #tags$ol(
      #tags$li("Chi-Square Filter"), 

      # ),  

    #strong('FEATURE SELECTION'),
    #br(),
    #br(),


      #actionButton("goButton2", "1. Feature Selection using Random forest"),
      #br(),
      #br(),

      #actionButton("goButton4", "2. Feature Selection using jRip"),

    fileInput("dataset", "Choose CSV File",
    multiple = TRUE,
    accept = c("text/csv",
    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
    ".csv")),
     #Include clarifying text ----
    helpText(em("Note: This app requires file in csv format only!!")),
    helpText(em("Note:Select all the inputs and click on button as given below to exectute the app")),
     #Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
     #Input: Select separator ----
    radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
      choices = c(Tab = ",",
     comma = "\t"),
    selected = ","),
    selectInput("select", "Select columns to display", names(data), multiple = TRUE),
   actionButton("update", "Update DataSet", class ="btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%'),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
   ),




    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("ABOUT",br(),p(tags$b("Feature Selection"), "is the process where you automatically or manually select those features which contribute most to your prediction variable or output in which you are interested in. Having irrelevant features in your data can decrease the accuracy of the models and make your model learn based on irrelevant features. Here in this web application we have tried to implement few of the feature selection methods which we have used in our research work. 
                                              "),br(),br(),p(tags$b(" Steps to be Followed")),
                           br(),p("First Click on the  'Output' tab which you want and then click the corresponding action button consisting of different feature selection methods in the side bar layout in order to view the results. The most important attributes of the dataset is displayed.  
                                                                                                                                                ")),
                  tabPanel("FEATURE SELECTION", br(),br(),actionButton("goButton2", " Feature Selection using Random forest"), textOutput("diswt2"),br(),br(),actionButton("goButton4", " Feature Selection using mop")),
                  tabPanel("CLASSIFICATION", textOutput("diswt5")),
                  tabPanel("DATA",DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
                  tabPanel("AUTHOR", br(),tags$h1("CONTACT US"),br(),br(),p(tags$b("Sachin, Joyal")),br(), p(tags$b("Department of Computer Applications")),br(),
                           p(tags$b("SNGIST Group of Institutions")),br(),
                           p(tags$b("N Paravur, Kerala,India")),br(),br(),p(tags$b("email:kavithacr@sngist.org"))))




    )

   )
)
```

server:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {


    observeEvent(input$goButton2,{
      source("randomfrst.R")
      output$diswt2<-renderPrint(wts2())})


    observeEvent(input$goButton4,{
      source("eg.R")
      output$diswt5<-renderPrint(wts5())})



    data <- reactive({
      req(input$dataset)
      read.csv(input$dataset$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep)
    })


     filtereddata <- eventReactive({
      input$update
      data()
    },  {
      req(data())
      if(is.null(input$select) || input$select == "")
        data() else 
          data()[, colnames(data()) %in% input$select]
    })

    observeEvent(data(), {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices=colnames(data()))
    })

    output$mytable  <- renderDataTable(filtereddata())
    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste(input$select, ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(filtereddata(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )

})
```

function:

```
library(mlbench)
library(FSelector)

wts2<-function(){
  ds<-sapnew
  weights <- random.forest.importance(class~., ds, importance.type = 1)
  #print(weights)
  subset <- cutoff.k(weights, 5)
  f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "class")
  return(f)
}
```

Comment: Sachin, I've edited your question to improve the code formatting. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to better format things. *Readability* is admittedly cosmetic, but if it is hard to read, it is more likely to be skipped-over by potential answerers.

Comment: Further, part of a good/reproducible MWE (minimal working example) is "minimal", meaning removal of things that are not required to make it run and just confuse it. Most of the commented-out code is not helpful. Just a suggestion!

Comment: thanks will do it for sure!

Comment: So the app appears to work for the most part, what is not working for you? If you are talking about just the `DATA` tabset being empty, replace `renderDataTable` (which is exported by `shiny`, incompatible with `DT::dataTableOutput`) with `DT::renderDataTable`. (Note the mention in https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html of *"collisions of functions of the same names in **shiny**"*.)

Comment: Yes it is working, but i want to do the feature selection from the uploded dataset. But in this code we can only import the dataset in r studio environment. Which i can use the dataset name as the object in the function randomfrst. I need the csv file that i am uploading to be accessed by the function. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: Within the shiny app, just reference `filtereddata()` directly by whatever function needs access to the selected fields. I have no idea what `randomfrst` is, so cannot comment with confidence, but if it is expecting a *file* as an argument, then I suggest changing what it is doing (as this is not an efficient workflow in a shiny app, IMHO).